# What is required to use the BrowserWindow, Playback and related classes?

Tags: code-reuse

I would like to use some of the classes that are available in Coded UI Tests, such as BrowserWindow, Playback, etc.

But I would like to be able to run the resulting code without using VS, MSTest, TCM, etc, since the code needs to run in tightly scrutinized production environments.

The first thing I ran into is the error:

```
"FileNotFoundException was unHandled" Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What do I need to do to get around this? More generally, can I use these classes that are available in Coded UI Tests and run the resulting code without using VS, MSTest, TCM, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install Visual Studio (or just the the Test tools) on the environment.